# pip install tenserflow in command

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I checked them,
python --version
Python 3.7.1

pip --version
pip 18.1

and I'm using Windows 10.

but,pip install tenserflow running command line,The following error comes out.

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: 
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ 
(Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Why?

Comment: you can try upgrade pip "python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org pip --upgrade"

Comment: Sometimes it could be caused because your network (public wifi or company VPN) prevents from connecting to the url.

Answer (score 0):

First, update pip by

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then install TensorFlow using

```
pip install tensorflow
```